# Dokku multi-process (container) with Dockerfile project

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dokku

I'm looking at http://progrium.viewdocs.io/dokku/process-management/ and trying to work out how to get several services running from a single project.

I have a repo with a Dockerfile:

```
FROM wjdp/flatcar

ADD . app

RUN /app/bin/install.sh

EXPOSE 8000

CMD /app/bin/run.sh
```

`run.sh` starts up a single threaded web server. This works fine but I'd like to run several services.

I tried making a `Procfile` with a single line of `web: /app/bin/run.sh`
 and removing the `CMD` line from the Dockerfile. This doesn't work as without a command to run the Docker container doesn't stay alive and dokku gets sad:

```
remote: Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container ae9d50af17deed4b50bc8327e53ee942bbb3080d3021c49c6604b76b25bb898e: Container ae9d50af17deed4b50bc8327e53ee942bbb3080d3021c49c6604b76b25bb898e is not running
remote: Error: failed to kill containers: [ae9d50af17deed4b50bc8327e53ee942bbb3080d3021c49c6604b76b25bb898e]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to use supervisord. Supervisord is a very lightweight process manager.

You would launch supervisord with your CMD, and then put all the processes you want to launch into the supervisord.conf file.

For more information, look at the Docker documentation about this: https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/ . The most relevant excerpts (taken from that page, but reworded):

You would put this into your Dockerfile:

```
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

And the supervisord.conf file would contain something like this:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:sshd]
command=/usr/sbin/sshd -D

[program:apache2]
command=/bin/bash -c "source /etc/apache2/envvars && exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND"
```

Obviously, you will also need to make sure that supervisord is installed in your image to begin with. It's part of most distros, so you can probably use yum or apt-get to install it.

Comment: Thanks, I have used supervisord before and this did come to mind but trying to follow Docker best practice I'm trying to avoid running more than one main process per container.

Comment: That said, this is probably the best option for now. Until docker compose support arrives.

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you are trying to do, then. I thought you wanted to run multiple processes in one container? That said, this guideline really is a very "mild" best practice. It's a good idea when it makes sense, but it often doesn't, and sometimes it's actually impossible to do. for instance, I had two processes that both connect to TCP sockets in the other. Linking does not support such circular dependency. So the choice was either to bind both sockets to host ports, or to put both processes in the same container.

Comment: I'm also curious how docker compose would fit in the picture?